# How to identify directory paths within multi-line string, replace with references to own file content, in Bash?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell, unix

Given a bash variable containing the following multi-line string representing *nix paths:

```
/some/app/path/dir1
/some/app/path/somefile1.txt
/some/other/app/path/somefile2.txt
/some/random/app/path/dir2
```

I'd like to be able to identify all directories (dir1 & dir2, for example) and to *replace* these directory path lines with the paths of the files below them. There should be no directory references in the final output, thus:

```
#Nodirectory references, just files.
/some/app/path/dir1/dir3/file1.xml
/some/app/path/dir1/dir3/file2.doc
/some/app/path/somefile1.txt
/some/other/app/path/somefile2.txt
/some/random/app/path/dir2/file3.png
/some/random/app/path/dir2/dir4/file4.txt
```

I'm not sure exactly how to iterate over the lines and remove/replace the directories, how could I do this?

I'm assuming the use of 'if' and various operators to identify directories, and 'find /my/dir -type f', to actually find the files.

I'm using Mac OSX 10.10 (Yosemite).

Comment: This is a file you are attempting to modify, correct? Not actual files on disk? Is the mapping from directory paths to file paths one-to-one? Can you determine a "directory path" by name? By pattern (no `.` in the final component)? Some other way?

Comment: @EtanReisner, no, it's not a file, it's the result of some previous bash calls (diff actually), that I'm storing in a variable for further processing within the script and its functions. I'm not using external temporary files, is that a good technique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test if the name is a directory. If it is, call `find`, otherwise just echo it as it is.

```
echo "$variable" | 
    while IFS= read -r name
    do
        if [[ -d $name ]]
        then 
            find "$name" -type f -print
        else
            echo "$name"
        fi
    done
```

Instead of piping `echo "$variable"`, you can also use a here-string:

```
while IFS= read -r name
do
    if [[ -d $name ]]
    then 
        find "$name" -type f -print
    else
        echo "$name"
    fi
done <<<"$variable"
```

Comment: @barmar, many thanks - only thing is, I need to do this for a list I have in memory, in a variable, as stated (????).

Comment: Pipe `echo "$variable"` to the loop. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @barmar, might I dare ask, how to I collate the output back into another, singular, variable? Apologies, and hey, take a rest [when you're done]. Thanks.

Comment: `var=$(while ... done <<<"$variable")` puts the output of the command into another variable.

Comment: How did you get this into the original variable if you didn't know that?

Comment: I just `someVar=$(diff -qwr /dir1 /dir2)` then did a few grep and awk calls to get the paths...

Comment: It is worth pointing out that using variables/strings for this means you **cannot** correctly handle paths with spaces and newlines in their names and might mean that you can't handle paths with shell globs/metacharacters in the names correctly either.

Comment: @Barmar, duh, didn't read your return variable comment correctly, yes, I already knew that, just haven't written a script for quite some time, and haven't used `while and if` statements in that time...

Comment: @EtanReisner You're correct about newlines in the filenames, but spaces shouldn't be a problem. There's no word splitting going on, it's reading line by line.

Comment: True, with `IFS=` word-splitting is avoided so spaces shouldn't be a problem.